# Link up an ms access database to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ms-access, oledb

I've installed the OLE DB Provider for JET by downloading [this](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=23734) and installing it.

I closed and reopened Microsoft SQL Studio, and connected to my SQL Server Instance.

In `<instance-name> -> Server Objects -> Providers` according to [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175866%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), there is now supposed to be an item named  `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0` or `Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0` item, but there is not.

Do I need to get this somewhere else?

Comment: I'm assuming you are on 64 bit. The jet provider is 32 bit.

Comment: So I need a 32-bit sql server instance...

Comment: That fixed it.  @RobertLDavis this one is yours if you answer it.